# Add to Cart button woocommerce background and with doesn't display correctly

Tags: css, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a problem with Add to Basket background and width display on mobile phone. I do not know why it has been like that.

Can you guys checkout my website https://www.theturkishshop.com and let me know how I can fix "ADD TO BASKET" button, which is displaying not correctly ( the background of the left is white). Thanks and look forward to hearing ideas from you guys.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `background-image: none !important;` to your buttons CSS.

Complete CSS-Rule:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart {
        background-image: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, it's been accepted. And thanks once again for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello You needs to add following css:

```
a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart {
    background-color: #CAA300 !important;
    background-position: 7% center !important;
    width: 77%;
}
```

Comment: I tried but the result is still the same. Can you check it on mobile and help me? it is really urgent. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use this in media query -> @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {